# ClassNotFoundException for HttpTransportOptions when using BigQuery

Tags: java, maven, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the BigQuery Java API as part of a larger project involving Dataflow and others. However, I'm getting the following error when running `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.xpw.bq_test`:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/HttpTransportOptions
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.getDefaultHttpTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:107)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$BigQueryDefaults.getDefaultTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:102)
    at com.google.cloud.ServiceOptions.<init>(ServiceOptions.java:255)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.<init>(BigQueryOptions.java:31)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$Builder.build(BigQueryOptions.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance(BigQueryOptions.java:141)
    at com.xpw.bq_test.main(bq_test.java:12)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.HttpTransportOptions
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

`bq_test.java` looks like:

```
package com.xpw;

import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class bq_test {

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {

        // Instantiates a client
        BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    }
}
```

My pom file dependencies in case a conflict could be causing the error:

```
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-rc2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
            <version>${beam.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-bigquery</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0-beta</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

So far I have tried:

1. Running `mvn clean` and rebuilding.
2. Removing `~/.m2/repositories` and rebuilding.
3. Adding `google-cloud-core` directly to my pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue before. I made some tweaks and the code snippet below worked for me.

```
TransportOptions options = HttpTransportOptions.newBuilder().setHttpTransportFactory(new HttpTransportOptions.DefaultHttpTransportFactory()).build();
GoogleCredentials credential = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
BigQuery service = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(YOUR_PROJECT_ID)
                        .setTransportOptions(options)
                        .setCredentials(credential)
                        .build()
                        .getService();
```

Please include the following dependency as well for GoogleCredentials.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.0</version>
  <type>jar</type>                
</dependency>
```

Try this and let me know.

**Note** :  Always be aware when using those libraries, make sure you use all of them with same build version. That's the only way to be secure and error free.
This happens a lot with Maven, playing with upgrading and downgrading dependencies to match with. In your case the group id "com.google.cloud" has two versions on the dependencies that's creating those conflicts. Use 0.11.0-beta for google-cloud-storage and it should resolve all future issues too

Comment: Thanks @bibek-adhikari but I'm still having the same error. Thrown on the line with `.setTransportOptions(options)`, but the stack shows `com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$Builder.setTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:70)` as the next line.

Comment: @MitchLillie Still the class not found error ? That should have gone, since we are building it explicitly. It's weird, hope you set the project id which is your default one.

Comment: Yes. I set the project ID as required. Relevant part of the stack trace:
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/cloud/HttpTransportOptions
 at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions$Builder.setTransportOptions(BigQueryOptions.java:70)
 at com.xpw.bq_test.main(bq_test.java:17)
 ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.cloud.HttpTransportOptions
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: @MitchLillie Lets remove other dependencies and just keep 2 of them, oauth and bigquery ones, let's verify if its the conflict that's causing a pain here.

Comment: @MitchLillie I do not see any reason to fail other than dependencies, i just re-verified it, dependencies with GCP Java library is so fragile. I faced a lot of similar issues before.

Comment: Definitely one of the dependencies... I guess I am not familiar with how Maven handles this kind of thing. I'm using IntelliJ, and when I comment out the other deps, it suggests I import a slightly different `HttpTransportOptions`, namely from `com.google.cloud.HttpTransportOptions`. If I run it at that point, with only BigQuery and the auth lib, it runs successfully. If I add the deps back to the pom, changing nothing, I get cannot find symbol for `HttpTransportOptions`. Any idea what is colliding from your experience?

Comment: @MitchLillie Yes, always be aware when using those libraries, make sure you use all of them with same build version. That's the only way to be secure and error free. This happens a lot with Maven, playing with upgrading and downgrading dependencies to match with. In your case the group id "com.google.cloud" has two versions on the dependencies that's creating those conflicts. Use 0.11.0-beta for google-cloud-storage and it should resole all future issues too.

Comment: Thank you! If you will add that info to your answer I will accept it.

Comment: @MitchLillie I updated those, feel free to reach me out with any problems you face on GCP,  we can try and resolve those  :)